# Submit Python script to Databricks JOB

Tags: pyspark, gitlab, databricks, azure-databricks, gitlab-api

Is it possible to submit/configure a spark python script (.py) file to databricks job?

I have my developments happening in my Pycharm IDE, then push/commit the code to our gitlab repository.  My requirement is I need to create new jobs in databricks cluster as and when a python script is moved to a GitLab master branch.

I would like to get some suggestions if its possible to create a databricks job on a python script, using gitlab.yml scripts?

In databricks Job UI, I could see spark jar or a notebook that can be used, but wondering if we can provide a python file.

Thanks,

Yuva

Answer (score 5):

This functionality is not currently available in the Databricks UI, but it is accessible via the REST API.  You'll want to use the [SparkPythonTask](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/jobs.html#jobssparkpythontask) data structure.

You'll find this example [in the official documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/examples.html#create-a-python-job):

```sh
curl -n -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @- https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/jobs/create <<JSON
{
  "name": "SparkPi Python job",
  "new_cluster": {
    "spark_version": "5.2.x-scala2.11",
    "node_type_id": "i3.xlarge",
    "num_workers": 2
  },
  "spark_python_task": {
    "python_file": "dbfs:/docs/pi.py",
    "parameters": [
      "10"
    ]
  }
}JSON
```

If you need help getting started with the REST API, see [here](https://docs.databricks.com/api/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Raphael, can it be done from gitlab by any chance?  Just curious